# PHP : Comparing string to true returns strange results

Tags: php

I would appreciate it if someone could explain to me why the following code...

```
$result = true;
if ($result == "discontinued"){
   echo "IN";
} 
if ($result == "invalid"){
   echo "IN2";
}
```

triggers both echos (ie. ININ2)....I know I can change the operator to === and it will work but I don't understand what is happening.  Thanks

Comment: Because [this](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) and also [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: haha the good old type juggling xD ... Btw. there is [strval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) to get the value from a (casted) string, also good for casting objects to string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using the comparison (`==`) operator anything that cannot be converted to false will evaluate to true. This includes any non-empty string. This is because of [type juggling in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). So  `"discontinued"` evaluates to true because it is not an empty string. If you use the the identical operator (`===`) type conversions are not done so `"discontinued"` is treated a literal string and your statement will then evaluate to false.

The following will evaluate to false when type juggling is performed. Everything else will be evaluated as true:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)